# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Число содержит синтаксическую ошибку в выражении запроса '01.12.202'."

Tags: c#, winforms, access

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\KursASS\Norm\KursAss\Television.mdb";
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
        command1.Connection = connection;
        command1.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO Телепрограммы (Код, Телеканал, Название_телепередачи, Тип, Жанр, Дата, Время_начала_передачи, Длительность_передачи, Время_окончания) Values (8, СТС, Негры_атакуют_40, Фильм, Трагедия, 01.12.2022, 22, 1, 23)";
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();     
    }
```

Comment: 01.12.2022 - это не число. Нужно взять его в кавычки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В самой таблице поле "Дата" имеет формат "краткий формат даты" и тип конечно "Дата и время"

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Попробовал '' - помогло, но теперь пишет что отсутствует параметр: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Отсутствует значение для одного или нескольких требуемых параметров."

Comment: Не задавайте вопросы в комментариях. Пишите всю необходимую информацию в самом вопросе. Его можно редактировать сколько угодно.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблема была в датах и оно решается если писать не так напрямую как я, а через AddWithValue что-то типа:

```
command1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Телепрограммы (Телеканал, [Название телепередачи], Тип, Жанр, Дата, [Время начала передачи], [Длительность передачи], [Время окончания]) Values (@Телеканал, @Название_телепередачи, @Тип, @Жанр, @Дата, @Время_начала_передачи, @Длительность_передачи, @Время_окончания)";
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Телеканал", comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Название_телепередачи", textBox2.Text);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Тип", textBox3.Text);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Жанр", textBox4.Text);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Дата", textBox5.Text);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Время_начала_передачи", textBox6.Text);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Длительность_передачи", textBox7.Text);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Время_окончания", textBox8.Text);
```